# Elements wrapping in div instead of scrolling

Tags: html, scroll

I am trying to create something simlar to a DataGridView in html. I will be pulling data from a database and inserting into my DGV. I have a limited space to work with for this DGV so I want it to scroll on both the x & y-axis. I have tried using tables and a div. When I try  either th tags or h4, the tags wrap instead of becoming scrollable along the x-axis.

```
<div id="dgv">
  <div><h4>Header1</h4><h4>Header2</h4><h4>Header3</h4><h4>Header4</h4><h4>Header5</h4>
</div>

CSS:
#dgv
{
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

#dgv h4
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `<div>` inside `<div id="dgv">` a width greater than its parent.  Try adding this CSS:

```
#dgv div {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

That should give you horizontal scrolling.  Likewise, if you want vertical scrolling, it'll need a height greater than it's container as well.

Think of `<div id="dgv">` as a window, and the `<div>` inside it as the canvas you're looking at through that window.  If the canvas is larger than the window, scrolling happens.  If no specific size is set for the inner `<div>` it just inherits it from its parent.

Answer (score 2):

Justin's answer might help in some cases. Few scenarios can be like below:

If your list element is `div`, then by default it'll take full width as parent. But items will wrap even if the list has `overflow: auto` property.

**Try this if you're using a box-model approach:**

```
.list {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap; // Will restrict children from wrapping
}
```

[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) guides the space inside `.list`.